# Best Third Button Placement in Website

Tags: website-design, buttons, redesign

I'm currently redesigning a website for internal staffs in a company, I have a case that users are filled in a form and can go to the next page the form and then there would be a print button in the same page. But the thing is I have then 3 buttons, there are "finish", "print" and "back". I just wondering where the best placement should be if there are 3 buttons in the same page. Users need to do the "print" first and then they could be "finish". At first I think I would place the print with icon and place it above the form, but that would be another research, as I don't really want to change their behavior that much (by placing print above the form).

the page before "print" button
[image: the page before "print" button]

my idea because they need to do "print" first, and then "finish". "finish" button would be disabled when user haven't clicked on "print" button
[image]

"print" button is left aligned so that the "finish" & "back" button stay at the same spot as "prev" & "next" button.
[image]

Comment: Is printing a mandatory step or an action everyone would perform? Could they maybe ‘finish’ and then see a summary that they can print?

Comment: Printing is mandatory step, users can't submit if they haven't print anything, but they could print multiple times while in this page (in case there are problems with the printer or smth) @greenforest

Comment: What would happen if the user clicks the ‘finish’ button? Is there a better wording that indicates what ‘finish’ really means? If printing is essential, you could consider making ‘print’ it’s own step and only show the option to ‘finish’ after the print button was used at least once?

Comment: so this task have multiple steps using stepper therefore the prev and next button. this particular one is the last step of the task, if you didn't print then you can't finish. finish means to send the form that already filled in to supervisor/someone that checked your task. I don't really understand what you mean by "show the option to ‘finish’ after the print button was used at least once".  so there would be 3 buttons again? or just print and finish? @greenforest

Comment: second screen seems right.

Comment: is it okay to put back button on the left? because the previous page, the secondary button "prev" are on the right side. @MadalinaTaina

Comment: @odp since printing and finishing is mandatory, why don't you just make one "print and finish" button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment it seems that Print is a mandatory step. Have you thought about making it a two-step process?

Through the normal next/back flow a step could be Print (Option 1). Once users prints it once, the finish is available to the user. However, you can still give the print option as a third menu for unlimited times printing (Option 2).

Also, is this actual physical printing? Or do you want to ask users if you want to validate the form before they finish?

[image]

Comment: oh right! I never thought of this because I'm too focused on disabling the button! And yes, this is physical printing, they need to print what they filled. I don't think I need user validation as the browser would pop up a card to preview the form that are going to be printed. thank you for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

As I read in the question and subsequent comments, it's very clear what the function of each CTA is but not the graphic resolution. In fact, if we omit the function, the question has the same meaning:

- Where to put three "rectangular" buttons at the bottom of a form?

My immediate answer is: if the action is clear and the graphic resolution is not, what fails is the element you are trying to use to solve it, the buttons.

If we remove this second part and only rescue the action, a series of icons solves the problem immediately, not only for the graphic part but also the syntactic and semantic: order and meaning.

[image]

Once the problem of order and function fair visibility  in the page layout is solved, we can start thinking about the usefulness of a button if necessary. A good contrast with the Cartesianism of a form can help to emphasize the meaning of action and order.

[image]

#### Answer update

These buttons can be square, this answer points to contrast to enhance meanings. I personally see graphically redundant rectangular buttons on a page riddled with rectangles. More rectangles help the general confusion described in the question.

If the use of rectangular buttons is imperative, there are several possible graphic options, for example gathering the icons into a single set of buttons.

[image]

Comment: I like the idea using icon button, but I don't know about clarity using icon button as this is a redesign and users are used to rectangular shaped button. Also there are a lot of form in the system using rectangular button to submit/back. I'm afraid the design won't be consistent?

Comment: Answer updated.–